# Does this type of graph have a name, and is its vertex cover problem solvable with an exact evaluation?

Tags: graph-theory

This graph looks like so:
https://ibb.co/mkOM06

The nodes are arranged in a line, and two nodes can only share a edge if the nodes between them are connected to either of the two nodes in question.

I'm sure there is a more rigorous way of putting it (excuse my lack of education in graph theory overall), I've reduced another problem to solving the vertex cover problem for this graph, so any information around that would be helpful.

Comment: In other words, if the vertices are labelled $1,\ldots,n$, then $E \subseteq \{\{u,v\}: 1 \leq v-u \leq 3\}$?